# How to make multiple webpages (webpage.com/1 , webpage.com/2, etc) that reference a MySQL database without repetition?

Tags: php, mysql

My apologies if this has been asked before, but I'm struggling to figure out the correct terminology to use when searching.

I'm currently learning PHP and MySQL while attempting to produce a website. The premise of which is that a user submits some data which is saved to a database, with a reference number (1234). Then if they access www.webpage.com/1234 the website loads with some particular parameters they have determined (and are accessed via MySQL).

How do I achieve this without producing an individual webpage for each item in the database?
I'm sure there must be a way to produce a 'master' webpage that references the numbered extension.

In short, something like this.

1. User stores their parameters in the database, receives a 'reference' number (1234)
2. Someone goes to the webpage www.website.com/1234
3. Webpage uses the number (1234) to access the relevant data and load accordingly

Comment: Look into using Apache mod_rewrite or try a framework (eg. Laravel) that will do this for you.

Comment: In the duplicate question, for "registered user" read "thing associated with the reference number"

Comment: You are looking for 'PHP routing' or 'PHP pretty URLs'.